# Share printer between Macs in different networks

Tags: network, printing, sharing, cups

I have one Mac Mini (running 10.11) with a HP P4015 printer attached via USB and shared via System Preferences => Sharing inside my network 10.161.5.x (IP range for machines attached to the cabled network) and a Macbook (running 10.13) in IP range 10.161.6.x (for machines in Wifi) and try to get printer sharing working. Routing between the networks *does* work, the machines can successfully ping and SSH each other, also accessing http://:631 CUPS interface works.

When the Macbook is attached via cable, I can add the printer as "Bonjour Shared" and print with it (obvious, they're on the same network). When it is attached via wifi (which is the normal case) it shows as "offline". The reason seems to be because the printer device URI is `dnssd://(garbage).macmini.local`, which cannot be resolved because the dnssd broadcast packets are not forwarded between the two hosts.

Is there a way to manually edit the device URI to use the proper hostname (macmini.mynet.tld) instead of the DNSSD hostname?

Comment: Have you tried to manually add the printer using the correct IP instead of from the recommendations in printer settings?

Comment: @KevinGrabher uh, how? Using LPD, IPP or Socket? If yes, which ones? I'm not aware that CUPS exposes printers that way.